# Create navigation drawer in vue with bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I want to create a basic admin panel with a side menu. It should look like this:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/baseline

I've got this so far:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        name: 'BootstrapVue',
        show: true
      }
    },
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 57px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-navbar variant="dark" type="dark" fixed="top">
      <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>
    </b-navbar>
    <b-container fluid>
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="2" class="pl-0">
          <b-nav vertical class="bg-light border-right position-fixed">
            <b-nav-item>
              This topic is way too long to be displayed correctly!
            </b-nav-item>
          </b-nav>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="10">
          <b-card no-body style="border: none;">
            <b-card-text>
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
                tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
                nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero,
                sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci
                eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, </h4>
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
                tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra
                nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero,
                sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci
                eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
              </h4>
            </b-card-text>
          </b-card>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the text of a menu item overlaps the boundries of the column and goes behind the main content (router-view). The text should break when it reaches the end of the column.

Comment: Have you tried adding z-index?

Comment: This only makes the text moving to the foreground. I only want the menu items to be as wide as the menu itself (no overlap at all).

Comment: Removing the `position-fixed` from the b-nav will solve your problem.

Comment: @dreijntjens Yes this solves the problem, but then the menu isn't fixed when you scroll on the main page.

Answer (score 2):

Give a `max-width` to you b-nav "(100 / 12) * cols" in your case this is (100 / 12) * 2 = 16.667%

```
<b-col cols="2" class="pl-0">
    <b-nav vertical class="bg-light border-right position-fixed" style="max-width=16.667%;">
        <b-nav-item>
            This topic is way too long to be displayed correctly!
        </b-nav-item>
    </b-nav>
</b-col>
```